# Dos variables evento onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy intentando meter un push en un evento onclick antes de darle el valor a `window.location`.

```
 href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location = 'pagina.php';"
```

Pero, el problema que tengo, es que si lo meto por delante con ',' o con ';', en el código que se genera, veo que aparece, pero se pierde la redirección a la pagina.

```
 href="javascript:;" onclick="variable.push('4'),window.location = 'pagina.php';"
```

Entonces no se como ponerlo.....he probado varias formas, pero siempre se fastidia el onclick.

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: La separación debería ser con punto y coma (`;`) y no con coma

Answer (score 2):

Por que no usar un file .js?

Pienso que es mejor que tu usar javascript como:

```js
document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click", function()
{
 console.log("primero");
    window.location="http://www.google.com";
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="clickme">
  Hello
</a>
```

Cuando se utiliza solo un file .html, es posible de escribir javascript  con el tag 'script'

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click",    function()
     {
    console.log("primero");
    window.location="http://www.google.com";
     });
</script>
```

Pero, es mejor que tu usar uno file para .html y uno file para .js.

Comment: el problema, es que no es id unico, tengo como 100, entonces no puedo usar el id, tendria que hacerlo de otra manera

Comment: ID debe ser unico (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Pero, es posible de usar onclick='myFunction()', y en javascript escribir 'function myFunction(){..}'

Comment: onclick="crear_data('<?='3'?>');"    he hecho esto, y que la funcion sea window.location=variable;    y tampoco me funciona

Comment: O.o usar onclick como esta no es bien. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

El problema lo tenes porque la variable no esta definida en el *onClick*.

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```html
<a href="#" 
onclick="var variante=[];variante.push('4');alert(JSON.stringify(variante));window.location.href='www.google.com'">Boton de prueba</a>
```